# How to prevent UIDragPreview snapshot resizing

Tags: ios, uidragitem

I can make a custom drag view during drag-and-drop like so:

`let d = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
d.previewProvider = { UIDragPreview(view: imageView) }`

But then if my imageView is 'too big', iOS will resize it down to something it thinks is better. But, it's wrong. Anybody know how to prevent this? The imageView I give it has the exact draggable size that I want...

Comment: Did you find out if that's possible?

Comment: @scrrr Sadly no - afaik it's not possible. I guess I'll leave this question there - maybe Apple will update things in the future...

Comment: Yeah I invested some more time as well and didn't find a solution either. Tried to use the moved-callback of iOS drag and drop to draw another shape on top but the movement was not smooth. I think I'll have to implement my own drag and drop for that reason which isn't so bad (at least in my use case.) But yeah leave it up for sure. Cheers mate